# Processing Newline character from Request Header in HAPI service

Tags: node.js, string, newline, hapi.js

I am trying some hands-on writing few services using `HAPI/nodejs`.
there are few "\n" which I am receiving in one of my header requests, I want them to be processed in the string and use it as a value newline rather than a string \n.

```
var key = request.headers.authorization;
```

I tried using `String(), toString() or eval()` but none seems to work.
Can someone please guide me where i could be missing something.

Appreciate help in advance,
-V

Comment: can you show your string and what your expected value?

Comment: Thats a RSA encrypted public key of my system cant share it, i am using ursa module to create public key from the string but that also expects the newlines properly, and that is where it is failing, just somehow want to preserve the newline, As far as code goes its simple:var key = request.headers.authorization; key should preserve newline however it maintains \n which is what is causing the problem

Comment: @vaibhav but you just said it was a public key... e.g. not private.